# Is it possible not to have $_GET values in views' exposed filters?

Tags: 7, views, uri

I can't seem to find a setting to do this nor am I familiar with any hook to implement this. Is it even possible?

I don't want to use ajax though.

Comment: Why would you want this? URL params are generally good. They make the results bookmarkable, shareable and indexable by engines.

Comment: in case of HUGE urls!

Comment: Seems you can't. Views exposed filters expect to receive parameters only via $_GET not $_POST

Comment: That's what I've come to believe too Eugene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the $_GET values are hardcoded into the exposed filters and that apart from using ajax (which In this use case I want to avoid) it can't be done. Will gladly pass the checkmark along if someone proves me wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

You can enable Ajax and extra stuff will not be added to the URL. 
If the problem is too long URLs, do a google search and see how short the URL is. However you can clean up the URL (that means you will use $_GET values) by setting a shorter URL parameter identifier.

Click on the exposed filter and expand the exposed filter settings. You will see a text field to enter the parameter string for this filter. Give a meaningful but tiny string.

For example, default URL would be  like:
path/to/view?field_my_weird_field=drupal

You can change it to:
path/to/view?text=drupal

Comment: I stated that I want to avoid ajax in my post :)
The second solution you propose might shorten the url, yes, but If I have a multiselect list and in some bizzare scenario the user selects 3k values from it, the URL's length will be unmanagable.